# How to speed up ordinal encoding of sparse categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

| idx | A | B | _target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [a,b,c] | [x,y,z] | … |
| 2 | [w,x,y] | [a,b,d] | … |

This is essentially the structure of my csv file, which I have loaded into python with pd.read_csv. columns A and B contain lists of categorical variables, a,b,c etc. A row cannot have a duplicate variable.

I want the instances when a variable is in A to be encoded as 1’s, and when in B they should be encoded as -1’s. When a row doesn’t contain a particular category in both A or B, that variable should be encoded as a 0.

I essentially need to transform it to this indicator table format:

| idx | a | b | c | d | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | … |
| 2 | -1 | -1 | 0 | -1 | … |

There are 250k rows and 25k unique categories (so hence columns). So memory is probably the main bottleneck here

Below is the code that I think should do the trick, but it won't run in any reasonable time frame.

```
sparse_A = pd.get_dummies(data["A"].explode(), sparse=True).groupby(level=0).sum()
sparse_B = pd.get_dummies(data["B"].explode(), sparse=True).groupby(level=0).sum()*-1
indicator_df = sparse_A + sparse_B
```

Any idea if there is a more efficient way to perform this operation?

Comment: Please read the following then edit your question to replace images with formatted text ; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you always have the same number of items in each list?

Comment: @mozway yep, 11.

Comment: @Cdot___ OK, then you can try with `crosstab` (see below), let me know how/if this scales!

Answer (score 0):

We can do it without `.explode()`; perhaps that will help with your memory issue:

```py
# test case

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [list('abc'), list('xyz'), 0.1],
    [list('wxy'), list('abd'), 0.2],
], columns=['A', 'B', 'target'])
```

Then:

```py
a = df['A'].apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies()
b = df['B'].apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies()
cols = a.columns.union(b.columns)

out = pd.concat([
    a.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0) - b.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0),
    df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1),
], axis=1)
out

>>> out
   a  b  c  d  w  x  y  z  target
0  1  1  1  0  0 -1 -1 -1     0.1
1 -1 -1  0 -1  1  1  1  0     0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your lists have the same number of values, you can use two [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
idx = df['idx'].repeat(3) # use here the list length as value

out = (pd.crosstab(idx, np.array(df['A'].tolist()).ravel())
       .sub(pd.crosstab(idx, np.array(df['B'].tolist()).ravel()),
            fill_value=0)
       .astype(int).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   idx  a  b  c  d  w  x  y  z
0    1  1  1  1  0  0 -1 -1 -1
1    2 -1 -1  0 -1  1  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
new_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        (dict.fromkeys(A, 1) | dict.fromkeys(B, -1) for A, B in zip(df.A, df.B))
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .assign(target=df.target, idx=df["idx"])
)
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b  c  x  y  z  w  d  target  idx
0  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  0  0     0.1    1
1 -1 -1  0  1  1  0  1 -1     0.2    2
```

---

Quick benchmark:

```py
from random import sample
from timeit import timeit


def setup_df(n=250_000, n_cats=25_000):
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append(
            {
                "idx": i,
                "A": list(map(str, sample(range(n_cats), k=11))),
                "B": list(map(str, sample(range(n_cats), k=11))),
                "target": 0.1,
            }
        )
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


def fn1(df):
    new_df = (
        pd.DataFrame(
            (dict.fromkeys(A, 1) | dict.fromkeys(B, -1) for A, B in zip(df.A, df.B))
        )
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .assign(target=df.target, idx=df["idx"])
    )

    return new_df


def fn2(df):
    idx = df["idx"].repeat(11)  # use here the list length as value

    out = (
        pd.crosstab(idx, np.array(df["A"].tolist()).ravel())
        .sub(pd.crosstab(idx, np.array(df["B"].tolist()).ravel()), fill_value=0)
        .astype(int)
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
    )

    return out


t1 = timeit(
    "fn1(df)", setup="df = setup_df(n=1000, n_cats=100)", globals=globals(), number=1
)
print(t1)
t2 = timeit(
    "fn2(df)", setup="df = setup_df(n=1000, n_cats=100)", globals=globals(), number=1
)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.01216180098708719
0.1373176029883325
```

Comment: impressive solution but fails with a MemoryError :(. needs to allocate like 43GB memory to create that 250kx25k dataframe which can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going for an approach where I iterate over columns, sorting out each column 1 at a time. Slow, but memory efficient, as I could change each column into a sparse dtype before moving on and sorting out the next column (perhaps there is a better way of doing this? I'm not sure)

```
# gather all vals in cols A and B
all_vals = []
for rowa,rowb in zip(data.A, data.B):
    all_vals += rowa + rowb

unq_categories = set(all_vals)

# sparse df creation
empty = np.empty([len(data.index),len(unq_categories)])
spr_arr = csr_matrix(empty)
sdf = pd.DataFrame(dtype="int8").sparse.from_spmatrix(spr_arr, columns=unq_ids)

for category in sdf:
    # transform column (implicitly turns it dense)
    sdf[category] = data.A.map(lambda category_list: 1 if category in category_list else 0).add(data.B.map(lambda category_list: -1 if category in category_list else 0))
    # make column sparse again to save memory
    sdf[category] = sdf[category].astype(pd.SparseDtype("int8",0))
```